Replacing silicone around shower door
I decided to replace silicone around shower door and partition. Currently silicone is only applied on the sides (both outside and inside) and at the bottom outside. As I was removing silicones at the bottom (outside)  I noticed that that there is water under silicone (hence probably mold). I am not sure how water is getting there. I noticed that partition and door has drainage holes inside, but they are above silicone level and probably not very useful. I also noticed that door and partition rubber seals are not very tight at the corners where they meat. 
Overall how can I prevent water from getting under silicone? This whole door and partition looks like very poor design or am I missing something?

Shower doors are designed to shed water, not be waterproof. The drainage slots allow the water that seeps in between doors and gaskets to drain back into the shower.
Unless you remove the shower door, apply a non hardening 1/16" inch butyl tape (find this at a good hardware store or glass shop) to the clean and dry shower base where the door frame sits and up each side about 6" and reinstall the door and frame, you will always have water under the bottom sill seeping in at some point through capillary action: the silicone starts to curl with repeated cleanings, gaps form and water enters where it can.
